# Is it possible to pack C develop environment to single file?

Tags: linux, windows, c

Is it able to pack components of least C compile environment (compiler, linker, header file, libc and so on) to single executable file?
Also  How do I do it?
I would like to make a portable C compile environment that able to store in a USB flash.

I want to devide package for each OS and architecture.(Target Arch: AArch64, x86, x86_64, RISC-V) (Target OS: Linux, window: if windows is supported each architecture)
I don't mind either gcc or clang.

Comment: Being able to target multiple architectures would reader header files that support those architectures.  You would also have to use different build environments to target those architectures

Comment: Yes.  It's called a `vmdk` or `qcow2` and it will contain a VM containing a Linux or other operating system install that contains all the tools you need, runnable under VMware or `qemu`.